# Run any application admin mode programmatically c#

Tags: c#, uac, privileges, administrator

I need to run my .exe with admin privileged. I searched google and found piece of xml which I need to put in app.config file. here is the `xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
<assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" processorArchitecture="X86" name="My Application" type="win32"/>
<trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
<security>
  <requestedPrivileges>
    <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator"/>
  </requestedPrivileges>
</security>
```

IS this enough to run any `exe` with `admin` privilegeS?. thanks.

Comment: Hard to decode what you are asking.  If you mean "does any process I start from this one run elevated as well?" then the answer is Yes.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but the requestedExecutionLevel element part is only the first half.
If the UAC is turned off, you have to perform a check for privileges and put up a error dialog if the user is not admin. 
You can get the privileges with the [WindowsPrincipal.IsInRole Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46ks97y7.aspx)

To create a Run as ... dialog take a look at this:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7168/RunAs-Class